# Python menu program, how to get option to call function designated function?

Tags: python, file, menu, return

```
def main():
menu()
choice()

if choice==1:
   option1()
elif choice==2:
    option2()
elif choice==3:
    option3()
elif choice==4:
    option4()
else:
    option5()
main()
```

I have made a menu with four different options (each are functions).
When I run the program, it prints menu(menu), prints prompt for choice(choice) and then ends. How do I get the choice to prompt option 1 function when 1 is selected? Here is the code

```
def menu():
print('Choose number to continue: ')
print('1 to create file')
print('2 to read file')
print('3 to append to file')
print('4 to calculate')
print('5 to quit')

def choice():
    choice=int(input('Enter menu choice: '))
    return choice


def option1():
    filename=input('Enter file name: ')
    file=open(filename,'w')
    print('Enter integers to be written to file and press enter when done.')
    count=1
    fox=1
    while count>=1:
        filedata=str(input('Enter integer '+str(fox)+' : '))
        count+=1
        fox+=1
        file.write(filedata)
        if filedata=='':
            file.close()
            break
```

I thought return would do the trick

Comment: But `return` to what? You need to actually call your function otherwise nothing inside it will actually run.

Comment: the functions are all called within the main as above

Comment: The problem is that choice is not being assigned to the variable it should be. A quick fix is below

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'choice' referenced before assignment, When I attempted that –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
    menu()
    t=choice()

    if t==1:
       option1()
    elif t==2:
        option2()
    elif t==3:
        option3()
    elif t==4:
        option4()
    else:
        option5()
    main()
```

Revised code.

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'choice' referenced before assignment, When I attempted that

Comment: I question the wisdom of having variables and functions with the same name.

Comment: Don't think that's the problem. They are in different scope